# The use of semirelative sensitivity for \$I_C\$ on \$V_{BE}\$?

Tags: bjt

When evaluating the quality of a bias network, we use the semirelative sensitivity to evaluate the sensitivity of \$I_C\$ to change with respect to \$V_{BE}\$, with the semirelative sensitivity being equal to: 
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial I_C}{\partial V_{BE}}\times\frac{1}{I_C}
\end{align}
My question is: why is it so? What are the benefits of using this value instead of the fully relative value of
\begin{align}
\frac{\partial I_C}{\partial V_{BE}}\times\frac{V_{BE}}{I_C}?
\end{align}

Comment: What is the "semirelative sensitivity" you refer to?

Comment: It's just because of common way to refer to Vbe  changes, you never say Vbe is changed 3% (which would call for a fully relative sensitivity) you most probably say Vbe has risen 20mV which best fits semirelative sensitivity.

Comment: It might be because when a BJT is biased it will always have approximately the same base-emitter voltage i.e. circa 0.7 volts irrespective of application. It's probably worth mentioning that Vbe changes approximately 26 mV per degree C and expressing a change in millivolts allows it to be compared with an equivalent change in temperature.

Comment: We use hFE for DC bias stability unless Vce drops below 2V when hFE begins to reduce from saturation towards Vce(sat) @Ic/Ib=10

Comment: Have you learned about transconductance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**"Sensitivity for Ic on Vbe"** ?

The sensitivity of Ic with respect to (changes of) Vbe is the most important parameter of a BJT - it is identical with the slope of the transfer characteristic Ic=f(Vbe) - and this is the so called "transconductance gm".

However, this parameter gm has nothing to do with something like a "quality factor". In contrary, we are interested in large values of gm because it determines primarily the voltage gain of an amplifier stage.

The quality of a bias network is a measure of the "stiffness" of the bias condition with respect to unwanted variations of surrounding influences like temperature, power supply, current gain hfe,...

As an example, the following expression defines the sensitivity of the collector current **caused by variations of the exponential Ic=f(Vbe) curve only (Ico and hfe constant)**.

That means; We are NOT interested in the slope of the exponential curve (gm=dIc/dVbe) but in the **change of the slope** caused by variations of the environment. These variations can be expressed by unwanted gm changes caused by Ic variations and - therefore, we need **Sx=d(gm)/d(Ic)=1/Vt** because of **gm=Ic/Vt** (Vt=temperature voltage).

Using the definition of gm=d(Ic)/d(Vbe) we, therefore, can write:

gm=d(Ic)/d(Vbe)=Ic/Vt and **Sx=1/Vt=[d(Ic)/d(Vbe)]/Ic**

Note that the stability factor Sx as defined above shows only the dependence of the transfer characteristic Ic=f(Vbe) with respect to the temperature voltage Vt - expressed by the corresponding Ic variations (and NOT yet the more relevant influence of Ico on temperature).